Kentico Message: The CSRF cookie was missing
I have a website built with K12.095 version.(Webform) There is tons of line in event log that says below error:
Message: The CSRF cookie was missing.
Exception type: CMS.Protection.Web.UI.CsrfException
Stack trace:
at CMS.Protection.Web.UI.CsrfProtection.EnsureCsrfToken()
at CMS.Protection.Web.UI.CsrfProtection.OnPostMapRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
at CMS.Base.AbstractHandler.CallEventHandler[TArgs](EventHandler1 h, TArgs e) at CMS.Base.AbstractHandler.Raise[TArgs](String partName, List1 list, TArgs e, Boolean important)
at CMS.Base.SimpleHandler2.RaiseExecute(TArgs e) at CMS.Base.SimpleHandler2.StartEvent(TArgs e)
at
System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
Even tough I can see the cookie named 'CMSCsrfCookie' is set to browser, I still have the error. What is the reason behind this? How can I solve the error? Thanks.


Have you checked  e.g. this: https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/cause-of-csrf-cookie-errors-in-the-event-log ? It could be coming from some bots, health checking software or similar.

Thank you. It does give us a clue to read the problem further. Regards,
